# Sharepoint 2010 adding custom visual webpart in master page with editable properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I can easily add webparts to my custom master page, but they appear static (in page edit mode)...Is there a way i can add custom webparts in master page with user editing its properties (through property bag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly In master page, visual web-part is not editable as they dont exist in web part zone, so now we use user control as delegate control.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the WebBrowsable attribute to your WebPart? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webbrowsableattribute.aspx

[Personalizable(), WebBrowsable(), WebDisplayName("My WebPart"), WebDescription("This is my editable WebPart")]